# Изменение лицензии на код

Tags: лицензирование, авторские-права

Доброго времени суток, господа!

Имею форк проекта, код которого выпущен под GPLv3. Модули, написанные мной, я выпускаю под MPL1.1. Имею ли я право изменить лицензию на другие модули с GPL на MPL если я сделал в них значительную часть изменений (естественно ссылаясь на первого автора)?

Comment: Я точно не знаю, но скорее всего потребуется согласие всех авторов. Погуглите переход Linux ядра с GPL2 на GPL3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Правообладатель (copyright holder), в данном случае - автор имеет право изменения условий лицензирования для новых релизов. Однако, поскольку, речь идет о производной работе, то правообладателем являются все авторы, независимо от вклада, поэтому общее согласие необходимо.

В любом случае, нельзя изменить правила лицензирования для уже выпущенных под GPL релизов, для них по-прежнему требуется предоставлять исходный код, и, соответственно, любой желающий сможет сделать форк.

Comment: И если в проект включены части под GPL, то и сам проект должен распространяться под GPL

Comment: Как я понял, то если все авторы, участвующие в проекте, будут согласны на изменение лицензии с GPL на MPL, то можно смело менять ее во всем проекте?

Comment: Смело - это будет пиратка :-)

Comment: Почему "пиратка" если все согласны на изменение лицензии?

Comment: @Валерий, а в чем собственно *суть проблемы* ?

Зачем Вам нужны все модули под одной лицензией, да и собственно, зачем Вам лицензии вообще ?

Comment: Сам задавался этим вопросом, но это прихоть юристов и начальства. Вроде как MPL дает возможность коммерциализации проектов под этой лицензией. Основа проекта была сделана под GPL, первый разраб уволился, работу продолжили под MPL. Вот и спрашиваю можно ли сменить с GPL на MPL, когда от GPL кода осталось всего лишь 300 строк, и то перелопаченных так что не узнать.

Comment: Понятно. Забейте на эти 300 строк. 

IMHO интеллектуальная собственность - это просто *неправильная вещь*.

Comment: > все согласны на изменение лицензии

Точно все? Правообладатель каждого патча и каждой копипасты?

> от GPL кода осталось

Ну сами же признаете, что производная работа...

Comment: да согласны, всего кодеров трое

Comment: > первый разраб уволился

А он согласен?

> все авторы, участвующие в проекте

**учавствовавшие**!

> прихоть юристов и начальства

А что говорят юристы?

Answer (score 3):

При переходе с `GPL2` на `GPL3` согласия обычно не требуется, так как в конце обычно написано: "... или более новой версии GPL".

Если вы выпускаете модули под другой лицензией (не `gpl3`), то Вы их должны распространять отдельно. Сам проект с вашими модулями или без вы можете распространять только под `GPL3`.

Исключение возможно, если исходный проект выпускается под несколькими лицензиями.

Comment: @drdaeman, читайте внмательно сму лицензию.
GPL-совместимость означает, что любой кусок кода разрешается распространять под GPL, т.е.описанный вами вариант соответсвует проекту под несколькими лицензиями: GPL на весь проект + другие совместимые лицензии на какие-то его части, но эти же части лицензируются и под GPL ввиду совместимости.

Comment: @drdaeman,читаем по вашей ссылке:

"... вы можете комбинировать текст, выпущенный по этой лицензии, с текстом, выпущенным по GNU GPL, в одной более крупной программе.

Все версии GNU GPL разрешают делать такие комбинации, не публикуя их; *они также разрешают распространять такие комбинации в случае, если комбинация выпускается по той же самой версии GNU GPL*. Другая лицензия *совместима с GPL, если она тоже разрешает это*."

Значит *весь проект распространяется под GPL*. И это означает что любая его часть, в том числе и то что лицензировано под другой лицензией, так же лицензируется под GPL.

Comment: @sercxjo: Да, Вы правы, я ошибался. Извините.